# Does it make sense to read from host memory in a compute shader to save a copy?

Tags: vulkan

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56687939) suggests using a compute shader to convert from packed 3-channel image data to a 4-channel texture on the GPU. Is it a good idea to, instead of copying the 3 channel image to the GPU before decoding it, write it to a host visible buffer, then read that directly in the compute shader?

It would save a buffer on the GPU, but I don't know if the CPU-GPU buffer copy is done in some clever way that this would defeat.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first question you need to ask is whether the Vulkan implementation even allows a CS to directly read from host-visible memory. Vulkan implementations have to allow you to create SSBOs in some memory type, but it doesn't have to be a host-visible one.

So even if you want to do this, you'll need to provide a code path for what happens when you can't (or just fail out early on such implementations).

The next question is whether host-visible memory types that you can put an SSBO into are also device-local. Integrated GPUs that have only one memory pool are both host-visible and device-local, so there's no point in ever doing a copy on those (and they obviously can't refuse to allow you to make an SSBO in them).

But many/most discrete GPUs *also* have memory types that are both host-visible and device-local. These are usually around 256MB in size, regardless of how much actual GPU memory the cards have, and they're intended to be used for streamed data that changes every frame. Of course, GPUs don't necessarily have to allow you to use them for SSBOs.

Should you use such memory types for doing these kinds of image fiddling? You have to profile them to know. And you'll also have to take into account whether your application has ways to hide any DMA upload latency, which would allow you to ignore the cost of transferring the data to non-host-visible memory.